# Is there any solution to where I can check and handle if browser UI has been closed?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to do a handle check **if the user closed the browser UI** in the midst of the crawling automation. Is this possible?

I believe the it only allows everything to run entirely until the process ends at `await browser.close();`.

```
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  // do something ...
  // if browser ui is closed/exit browser ui in midst of automation
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Can you not run it `headless`?

Comment: some web content needs to be loaded first before before it can be crawled.

Comment: Why does that prevent you from running it headless?

Comment: Can you listen for the `disconnected` [event](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#event-disconnected) on the browser object.  So, if that event occurs before you intended to close the browser, then it must have been aborted for some other reason.